# Infinite loading during checkout process with Payflow

Tags: magento2, onestepcheckout, paypal-payflow-pro

I have upgraded Magento version from 2.2.1 to 2.2.8, and I was using Braintree as a payment processor for CC payments. Now I enabled Paypal Payflow, but facing an issue.

I am trying placing order through Paypal Payflow Pro(credit card payment method) and I couldn't place the order successfully. However, when I have tried paying through PayPal Express then order got placed successfully.
In the case of CC, it is showing endless loading and when I refresh the checkout page, it redirects to the empty cart page. I have checked in the database, the cart is available in the database but the session is getting expired.
Anyone have faced this type of issue or anyone know the solution of this issue?

I am using Magento 2.2.8.

There is a discussion on this issue, [Infinite loading during the checkout process with payflow](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Infinite-loading-during-checkout-process-with-Payflow/td-p/78244). But the solution accepted is not valid in my case, because we can't use a fresh installation at the moment.

I am using Aheadworks onestep checkout extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked the Magento PayFlow code, and the requests checkout page is sending to the PayPal server and found that the issue is only appearing in the chrome browser. I have checked in Firefox and Edge and it is working fine in both browsers. I did some research on the issue and found it is a bug in the PayFlow Magento code and here is the complete discussion on the task https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26840. It is because of an update in the chrome browser, and they have provided a patch for this issue as well.

I have applied the patch on a Magento 2.3.4 development instance, and it is working fine. Sadly the patch is not working on Magento 2.2.8, but I am posting this answer, in case if someone is facing the same issue can follow the same thread to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar issue on M2.3.3 with Amasty's homepage checkout extension.

Comment: I have fixed the issue, and posted the answer. Please check it, in case if this can help you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did even think about the SameSite Cookie Changes. Our customers did mention that payment went through when switching to Firefox and Safari.

Answer (score 0):

My Payflow issue was caused by the store switcher adding store information to the paypal/transparent/redirect/

The page would never finish loading, no errors.

Under store switcher on our site was a location

Allowed Pages with exceptions

checkout/* plus others

I added

paypal/*

and that solved the payflow never finish loading page for us. Hope if others are searching for payflow issues that this may help.